# Trying to get specific value from a list and assign to new list using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm having a list which consists of ID and Value. I want to take that lists value and assign to new list based on their ID.

THis is my storages list: `var storages = UnitOfWork.Select<Storage>();`

1st list:

```cs
var smallZonesLoadedAmount = UnitOfWork.Select<LoadingDocumentObject>()
    .Where(x => x.LoadedWeight > 0 && x.StorageId.HasValue)
    .GroupBy(x => x.StorageId)
    .Select(group => new {StorageId = group.Key, LoadedWeight = group.Sum(y => y.LoadedWeight) })
    .ToList();
```

2nd list:

```cs
var smallZoneInfo = storages.Where(/*x => x.ZoneId == 2 &&*/ x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Number))
    .GroupBy(y => y.Number)
    .Select(z => new ZoneInformationView
    {
        ZoneName = z.Key,
        TotalCargo = smallZonesLoadedAmount.Where(x => z.Any(s => (int)s.Id == x.StorageId))
            .Select(x => x.LoadedWeight)
            .FirstOrDefault(),
        ZonePermissibleUsage = 0,
        CargoWithLongestStoringTimeInDays = 0,
        AverageLoadingUnloadingInDays = 0,

    }).ToList();
```

I'm expecting to take values from `smallZonesLoadedAmount` and put them into `smallZonesInfo` based on storages ID and `smallZonesLoadedAmount StorageID`.

Comment: What's the issue then? any errors?

Comment: I found the issue that I can't use "Any" inside constructor.  Issues with DB

Comment: What is your database? please tag it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code ,

```
var smallZoneInfo = storages.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Number))
    .GroupBy(y => y.Number)
    .Select(z => new ZoneInformationView
    {
        ZoneName = z.Key,
        TotalCargo = smallZonesLoadedAmount
            .Where(loaded => z.Any(storage => storage.Id == loaded.StorageId))
            .Sum(loaded => loaded.LoadedWeight),
        ZonePermissibleUsage = 0,
        CargoWithLongestStoringTimeInDays = 0,
        AverageLoadingUnloadingInDays = 0
    })
    .ToList();
```

here the methods `.Where` and `.Any` is used to filter and associate values from `smallZonesLoadedAmount` based on matching `StorageId` or `Id` from `storages`. And also calculated the `TotalCargo` for each group by summing the `LoadedWeight` values of matching elements from `smallZonesLoadedAmount`.